# Basic Form - Javascript Code Not working

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm having trouble getting this code to work. I am trying to create a URL from any text put into the form. For instance, if you submit "Hello" in the text field, it will result in "http://www.Hello.com." Any indicators as to why this isn't working would be appreciated.

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<form name="search" action="jsTest.html" onsubmit="return URL()" method="post">
Query: <input type="text" id="query" name="query"/><br>
Submit: <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function URL()
{
var x = document.search.query.val();
document.write("http://www.");
document.write(x);
document.write(".com/");
return false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the script tag closed?

Comment: Yes it is, forgot to paste that in. Sorry

Comment: You define a variable "x", but don't use it. You use a variable "query", but don't define it. I get the feeling that you're not really showing us your real code.

Comment: You and Joe are both right, I'm not using the x variable. However, upon pressing submit, no action persists.

Comment: Let me throw the complete code in, hold on one moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

```
<form>
Query: <input type="text" id="query" name="query"/><br>
Submit: <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getURL()"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function getURL()
    {
    var x = document.getElementById("query").value;
    alert(x); //Debug statement
    }
</script>
```

Righteo. No idea what's happening here, so I rewrote it from scratch. This works, I tested it, at the very least, to use the `alert` box.

**What may have been happening:**

I think that javascript functions might need to start with a lowercase letter.

From w3schools:

> JavaScript is case sensitive. The function keyword must be written in
>   lowercase letters, and the function must be called with the same
>   capitals as used in the function name.

I removed the `action` from the form, because it was most likely trying to find that file and activate the javascript code in that file.  I removed `post` because that was screwing up on my computer, probably because it was running in offline browser mode (ie, not actually using HTTP requests like POST wants)

`onclick` is all lowercase, not camelcase, which might have been causing some issues too. I always use `onclick` rather than using `form onsubmit` because generally your form will want to link to a `.PHP` file, whereas using the button's `onclick` allows for extra flexibility.

Comment: So I tried using val here, and have matched up my variables to make more sense. However, I'm still finding that the query goes directly to the end of the URL, without displaying a result.

Comment: @mkayen I've fixed up the errors, I think that might work but I haven't tried it myself. My answer's in pure javascript (no jquery), and I have included a debug statement that will use a pop-up box to tell you what the `value` of the `query` field is.

Comment: I'm still running into some issues here. In fact, the alert(x) isn't happening. Thanks for your help here, I really do appreciate it

Comment: When I click submit on the page, the alert does not occur, and no result appears either. There has to be something wrong with how I am writing the function.

Comment: @mkayen aha. That's why we do debugging. I figured something wonky was happening here.

Comment: @mkayen Fixed it, more info coming in a second!

Comment: Fantastic! Looking forward to seeing what you found

Comment: @mkayen My results (largely conjecture) have been added in. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Yes, this is really great. Works for me as well! Thanks for your help here!

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive but you can name you functions with any case you like only the `function` keyword needs to be in lower case.

Answer (score 1):

You set the `x` variable but refer to the undefined `query` variable. Keep your names consistent.

Comment: You are correct Joe, thanks for that. When I press submit, it only adds ".../jsTest.html?query=INPUT", without changing the actual content of the page. Do you know why this would happen here?

Comment: Add `return false;` to the end of your function. Sorry I am on my phone and can't edit my answer.

Comment: I'm still finding that the query goes directly to the end of the URL, and not displaying the expected result. I appreciate your help here!

Comment: You'll need to change the function call too. `onsubmit="return URL()"` along with the URL function returning false.

Comment: Nope. I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the form action. Should I have the submission flow to another page?

Comment: When I add method="post" to the form, the URL does not change (as expected), but no result appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your javascript. I suggest you to using jQuery.

```
function modify_url(){
        var q = $('input[name="query"]');

        q.val('http://www.' + q.val() + '.com');
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Let them understand what is underlying first, before taking off the training wheels.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.value` not `val()`, which is jQuery.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/wCS9d/

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! Is there any reason why you used getURL() rather than URL() ? Is URL() a built in JS function?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of line 6 in your JS?

Comment: I will admit I had trouble with `URL` so went with `getURL` instead. Line 6 sets the content of the `div` tag with id of `result` to the url. This is considered better practice than `document.write`

Comment: Also `console.log(res);` is a debug statement, just one that is less intrusive than an alert. Feel free to remove it.